# Fastest way tp post as a website on behalf of a website's user that has linked its Facebook account?

Tags: facebook

I have a website, where users can register via Facebook.

The question is how can I post, on behalf of a Facebook-registered user, on his/her own wall? so WITHOUT his/her direct intervention? Now I can only open a Share pop-up window so the user must be logged and also decide if he/she want to post or not.

A Facebook-approved Graph API app is the only way?

Thank you in advance.

Carlos.

Comment: What are you posting and when?

Comment: Your app should only post in the name of the user, if the user actively triggered it. Your app is not allowed to decide when and what to post for them.

Comment: Thank you for your replies, we will apply for Open Graph then....